# How to reverse this scroll animation?

Tags: jquery, css, text, infinite-scroll

I have this simple that I'd like to use for my website. The problem is that I would like to scroll the text down. So basically the other way around, but I can't make it. Is it possible to reverse the scrollTop() somehow?

HTML

```
<div id="list">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <span>Item 4</span>
    <span>Item 5</span>
    <span>Item 6</span>
    <span>Item 7</span>
    <span>Item 8</span>
    <span>Item 9</span>
    <span>Item 10</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#list {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

#list span {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: yellow;
}

.item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

JS

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('#list').stop().animate({scrollTop:40},400,'swing',function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0).find('span:last').after($('span:first', this));
  });
}, 1000);
```

Here you have a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e5dtyLjw/4/

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your animation, here is the sequence:

- scroll animation of 40 pixels
- move the first element (the one that overflowed on top) at the bottom
- reset the scroll position zero (because the first element was moved)

Now to reverse it, you need to:

- move the last element on top
- set the scroll position to 40 pixels
- animate scroll to position zero

The main difference between the two is about the element "move" done before the animation versus after (on callback of animate).

```js
setInterval(function(){
  $('#list').prepend($('#list').find('span:last'));
  $('#list').scrollTop(40).stop().animate({scrollTop:0},400,'swing')
}, 1000);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#list {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

#list span {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: yellow;
}

.item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <span>Item 4</span>
    <span>Item 5</span>
    <span>Item 6</span>
    <span>Item 7</span>
    <span>Item 8</span>
    <span>Item 9</span>
    <span>Item 10</span>
</div>
```

Feel free for any questions... ;)